# How to get 0 out of a null linq query value when a condition isn't met and then set it to a ViewBag

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I have a view bag set to the value of a linq statement to get all shift info. The linq statement is also set to a condition. when the condition isn't met, I get a null value and an error. I still want to be able to see the application when the condition isn't met, just not the data. I have seen examples with if else statements and the ternary approach (ie. ?? 0). I can get the viewbag to have a value of 0, but I need the actual property to have a value of 0.

The view bag in my controller is below:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string @Shift_ID)
        {

   ViewBag.ShiftName = db.TblShiftInfo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Shift_ID == @Shift_ID);
```

calling the viewbag in my view.

Shift Name :  @ViewBag.ShiftName.Shift_Name

So basically I need `@ViewBag.ShiftName.Shift_Name` to have a value of 0 when `c => c.Shift_ID != @Shift_ID`
when the condition isn't met.
Also I am using asp.net core. I have seen a lot of examples on how to get my desired outcome right inside my linq statement, but none of those solutions are supported by .net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this would work:

```
<strong style="color:white">@(ViewBag.ShiftName?.Shift_Name ?? "0")</strong>
```

Comment: He probably wants `"0"` instead of `string.Empty`.

Comment: @Tvde1, that's right, I completely missed that. I've fixed my answer. Thank you